# How to set custom hostname for a PostgresDB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, hostname

I am trying to setup a postgres DB on my AWS ec2 instance using the docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). What I would like to do is configure it's hostname. Is there any way to do that.The business use case is:
Let's say I have multiple customers and I would like to host a preconfigured postgres db on separate ports on the same ec2 server. The customers should be able to connect to these instances from their own psql. So I would like the connection string to be something like

```
postgresql://postgres:<password>@customer1.mywebsite.app:5443/postgres
```

Or

```
postgresql://postgres:<password>@<custom_domain_name>:5443/postgres
```

I tried using something like [caddy](https://caddy.community/t/using-caddy-as-a-reverse-proxy-in-a-home-network/9427) to proxy my requests but how to authenticate using the password for advanced Postgres configurations?
Is there a way to achieve this? I am not looking for a dockerised solution or ec2 specific solution. I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the domain name of the database on AWS. because the database is present on the AWS server and specific IP is associated with it. which is default configured on AWS. (Changing domain name means changing its IP address)

(solution)
You can create different users for your customers to access this database with specific privileges.[read, write, execute]